# Is there a way to give soft credit to all Affiliated Contacts (NPSP)?

Tags: contact, opportunitycontactrole, npsp

My organizations receives donations from both individuals and foundations. When a foundation donates, I want to give soft credit to everyone associated with the foundation (founders, employees, board members, etc), preferably all affiliated contacts.

I know soft credit can be done through the donation (oppurtunity) object by adding contact roles for each donation, but I don't like having to enter all the roles manually for each donation.

Example: The Doe Foundation gives $100. We enter the donation and link the Foundation as the giving account, which gives it hard credit. However, I'd then like it to automatically give soft credit to all Contacts that are part of the foundation, such as John Doe, Jane Doe, and their employees.

What's the best way to assign this soft credit?

Thank you

Comment: I see this was a while ago, but you will likely get speedy response to NPSP questions on the PowerOfUs Hub, at https://powerofus.force.com/ There is an active Q&A comnmunity with many NPSP Devs and Foundation Staff contributing to answers. Log into the with your SalesForce login